# Getting SwiftUI to show List items one at a time

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-list

Swift 5.x iOS 13.4

I wrote this code to show items in my list one at a time, it works :) But I think there is a better way, a more SwiftUI ??

```
 List {
      ForEach((0 ..< self.selections.count), id: \.self) { column in
        HStack(spacing:0) {
          Spacer()
          Text(self.selections[column].name)
            .opacity(self.showMe[column] ? 1 : 0)
            .font(Fonts.avenirNextCondensedBold(size: 22))
          Spacer()
            .onAppear(perform: {
        for i in 0..<6 {
          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i)) {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 8.0)) {
              self.showMe[i] = true
            }
          }
        }
      })

        }
      }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)
      .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0)
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 180.5, alignment: .center)
      .offset(x: 0, y: -64)
```

Comment: seems ok :) may be you can extract that logic somehow into an extension

Comment: that `showMe` animation looks like a performance hit in `onAppear`. Looks like it will loop the same `0...5` for every `column` `Text`. So that's about `6 * selections.count` times. But... why? what is this `showMe`? show us